# Firebase: Send user his password after manually creating account

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on an app for which users are manually created by supplying the user's email. So after the admin types in the email, this function is triggered:

```
emailSignUp(email: string) {

var password = "";
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  password += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

console.log(password);

return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((user) => {
    this.authState = user
    this.updateUserData()
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

}

Now the user is suppose to receive an email with his password which will be changed on first login.

Or maybe the user can get the verification email in which the password can be included. So he can verify his email and get his password at the same time.

Comment: whats the problem? or do you intent to share your code^^

Comment: That is my code. Is more needed?

Comment: Yeah? Because we don't know what your problems are

Comment: I don't know how to send emails after creating a user. But from what I'm reading online I don't think that's even possible. And the email template for the email authentication can't be edited so I can't send the password. I might have to try something else.

Comment: You could try using [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). [Example of emailing users.](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users) You won't be able to get the plaintext password from an auth trigger, so you could experiment with using an [HTTP trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

Comment: I found those functions on Github too. Thank you.